# Why can I see .MOV in my iPhone solely on my Windows 10, but not on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video

On my iPhone, I see many .JPG — but I see no .mov. After I plug in my iPhone into my Windows 10 desktop, THEN [I see all these .mov](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/437332/450729)! Why?

Many — but not all — these .mov have the same file name as the .jpg, and are video recordings of the objects of the pictures. Have I accidentally been videoing the objects of my photographs???? I have not deliberately selected video though! I can't believe I would have accidentally clicked on video so many times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking Live Photos. Windows cannot handle these properly as part of the photo, so the movie files are listed separately.

See [Apple KB - Take and edit Live Photos](https://support.apple.com/HT207310) which covers the iPhone aspect. Apple provides no support for them in Windows, so you have to handle them as two separate files.

<sup>I don't know this for a fact, but this might be why the phone will not let Windows throw out half of what it considers a single Live Photo, from your other question - [Why does File Explorer bring up permission errors, when I try to delete files from my iPhone on my Windows desktop?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437332/why-does-file-explorer-bring-up-permission-errors-when-i-try-to-delete-files-fr)</sup>